# how to replace modified object in array of objects using react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

i have object structure like this,

```
[{
"id":"8661c8c96df94ac78283360e0d1c86bd",
"modifiedObject":{....},
"originalObject":{...}
},
{
"id":"1525drd616dr17d78283360e0d1c86bd",
"modifiedObject":null,
"originalObject":{...}
},
{
"id":"6767srsr14542525276767cbd246464",
"modifiedObject":{....},
"originalObject":null
}]
```

I am finding an object with the id and get the inner object(if modified object present if not original object) and then modifying the data using below code

```
    const originalCopyObject = projObjs.find(s => s.id === projectObjectId);
    const targetCopyObject = originalCopyObject.modifiedObject || originalCopyObject.originalObject; // here in this case it always be one either modified or original object
    const targetMutatedCopyObject = cloneDeep(targetCopyObject);
    if (!targetMutatedCopyObject?.glazingOrGasMaterials.length) {
      targetMutatedCopyObject.glazingOrGasMaterials = [
        ...targetMutatedCopyObject.glazingGasMaterials,
        ...targetMutatedCopyObject.glazingSimpleMaterials,
      ];          
    }
    targetMutatedCopyObject.opaqueConstructions.forEach(transformConstructions);
```

Now `targetMutatedCopyObject` is having one of the modifiedObject or originalObject, How can I replace this targetMutatedCopyObject object in `projObjs`.

Could any one please let me know how to replace this `tragetMutatedCopyObject` in `projObjs` array of objects.

Many thanks in advance.

Updated Code :

```
   projObjs.map(projObj => {
    if (projObj.id === projectObjectId) {
      const targetCopyObject = projObj.modifiedObject || projObj.originalObject;
      const mutatedCopyObject = transformFormStateToMutationObject(targetCopyObject);
      if (projObj.modifiedObject) {
        return {
          ...projObj,
          modifiedObject: mutatedCopyObject
        };
      }
      if (projObj.originalObject) {
        return {
          ...projObj,
          originalObject: mutatedCopyObject
        };
      }
      return projObj;
    }
    return projObj;
  });
}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you would copy, or map, the old object to a new object reference. If the id matches the currently mapped element, return new object with the updated/modified properties, otherwise return the current element.

```
projObjs.map((projObj) => {
  if (projObj.id === projectObjectId) {
    const targetCopyObject = projObj.modifiedObject || projObj.originalObject;

    const targetMutatedCopyObject = cloneDeep(targetCopyObject);

    if (!targetMutatedCopyObject?.glazingOrGasMaterials.length) {
      targetMutatedCopyObject.glazingOrGasMaterials = [
        ...targetMutatedCopyObject.glazingGasMaterials,
        ...targetMutatedCopyObject.glazingSimpleMaterials
      ];
    }

    targetMutatedCopyObject.opaqueConstructions.forEach(transformConstructions);

    return {
      ...projObj,
      modifiedObject: targetCopyObject
    };
  }

  return projObj;
});
```

## Edit to return updated objects back into their original object keys

Factor the object update logic into a utility function and apply some branching logic on the `modifiedObject` and `originalObject` values in order to return an updated object back to the appropriate key.

```
projObjs.map((projObj) => {
  if (projObj.id === projectObjectId) {
    const updateObject = (targetCopyObject) => {
      const targetMutatedCopyObject = cloneDeep(targetCopyObject);
      if (!targetMutatedCopyObject?.glazingOrGasMaterials.length) {
        targetMutatedCopyObject.glazingOrGasMaterials = [
          ...targetMutatedCopyObject.glazingGasMaterials,
          ...targetMutatedCopyObject.glazingSimpleMaterials
        ];
      }

      targetMutatedCopyObject.opaqueConstructions.forEach(
        transformConstructions
      );

      return targetMutatedCopyObject;
    };

    if (projObj.modifiedObject) {
      return {
        ...projObj,
        modifiedObject: updateObject(projObj.modifiedObject)
      };
    }

    if (projObj.originalObject) {
      return {
        ...projObj,
        originalObject: updateObject(projObj.originalObject)
      };
    }

    return projObj;
  }

  return projObj;
});
```

***Note:** Be sure to capture the returned result from `projObjs.map` to update any parent object. This will be the new updated array.*

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, is this works for if `projObj` is only having originalObject not the modified object

Comment: @EnigmaState If I understand this follow-on question, you're asking if this works if the original data object have only the `originalObject` (i.e. no `modifiedObject`) property? Yes, I believe so as the `projObj.modifiedObject || projObj.originalObject` will grab `originalObject` if no `modifiedObject` exists, apply the logic, and place the new modified object in the `modifiedObject` property, preserving the `originalObject` property (provided all your logic is correct and doesn't mutate it, which I think is the case since you deep clone it).

Comment: oh sorry, i need to replace the exact object property, if `projObj` only having the `originalObject` then i should replace the existing with modifed originalObject property(here in case `targetMutatedCopyObject`) based on `Id` and do not want to preserve

Comment: @EnigmaState Ah, so if the original object has a `modifiedObject` property and that is the one you update you want it to go back on the `modifiedObject` key, and if it has only the `originalObject` property you want it to go back on the `originalObject` key? Is this correct understanding?

Comment: yeah that is correct, and it is always only one object property(either original or modified) present and other one is always null, is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: @EnigmaState Ok, got it, please check updated answer & explanation to see if that fits your needs and resolves your question.

Comment: it's looks like i am not getting modified object merged.. i am getting transformed object but it looks like it is failing here ` if (projObj.originalObject) {
        return {
          ...projObj,
          originalObject: mutatedCopyObject
        };
      }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227505/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-enigma-state).

Comment: any other way could you please suggest